# Modify <script> src or <a> href of elements dynamically added to page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

I'm writing a proxy at 
    https://myserver.com/proxy/[target/path].

It makes request to https://targetsite.com/[target/path], gets the HTML page, then loads it back to the user accessing the proxy. I already have regex's to modify the initial HTML response src's and href relative url attributes to point to /proxy/[target/path] instead of /[target/path].

However, sometimes "a" and "script" tags are dynamically added by javascript. How can I "intercept" these modifications to the DOM?

(With XHR and fetch, I was able rewrite the prototype for those Javascript API's to automatically rewrite requests to url's starting with '/'.)

My server runs on Node, but couldn't find any libraries that do this.

Comment: Detecting the presence of code that might be an anchor or script tag would be difficult. You could inject some js of you own into the page that detects changes to the dom (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219758/detect-changes-in-the-dom). Since you are essentially executing a man in the middle attack.

Comment: I don't think you really can.  You'd have to inject client-side Javascript to track all possible ways a `<script>` tag could be inserted into the DOM and a `.src` property set.  It might be easier to find any references to the old domain in the Javascript and change those to the proxy domain.